# Why aren't all Jersey filters @PreMatching by default?

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0

This is more of a theoretical question, why aren't Jersey `ContainerRequestFilter` configured as `@PreMatching` by default, as post-matched filters are?

This way we could have total access of the HTTP Request, which as far as I can see is what we generally want.

Are there any undesirable effects of `@PreMatching` then?

Comment: _"This way we could have total access of the HTTP Request"_ - What does this mean? What is the "total request". In a post-matching filter you have access to the matched resource method, which there are _many_ use cases for. You do not have this in a prematching filter.

Comment: I meant that we can redirect the HTTP Request to another Resource, edit it, I was not clear about it, I am sorry

Comment: Paul, shouldn't then the Resource be selected, but not created? Like a reference to a Type? I am now aware of the use cases, maybe they all need an object?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure. That's a good question. Something maybe the authors might have to answer. I'm sure they had their reasons for making this decision.

Comment: I thought you were one of the authors, since you always answer Jersey related questions.